# r data.table - shift/lead - accessing value of multiple row

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to access the value of multiple previous rows? I would like to look up the value into the previous row (more like cumulative or relative way) e.g. get value from the column as a list from all previous rows

e.g. see below reference code which is calculating unbiased mean by excluding existing row. I am looking for an option to exclude all previous rows from the current row (i.e. relative processing) Based on my assumption, I am assuming that shift will allow us to access the previous or next row but not the value from all the previous rows OR all next row.

http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#method-1-in-line

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[,.(cyl, gear, mpg)]
dt[, dt[!gear %in% unique(dt$gear)[.GRP], mean(mpg), by=cyl], by=gear] #unbiased mean
```

Comment: `shift` from `data.table` can take a vectorized `n` i.e. `shift(head(iris$Sepal.Length), n = 0:5)` which returns a `list` of vectors.  This can be reduced with `Reduce("==", shift(head(iris$Sepal.Length), n = 0:5))`. One thing to consider is the `NA` default in `lag/lead` which may or may not be good while we use `==` (as it returns NA).  It can be correceted by changing the default values i..e `Reduce("==", shift(head(iris$Sepal.Length), n = 0:5, fill = first(iris$Sepal.Length)))`

Comment: I added a reference link and example.